# Python Selenium, Scraping LinkedIn: Looping through Work and Education Histories

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, linkedin-api

I am scraping data from LinkedIn profiles in Python using Selenium. It is mostly working but I can't figure out how to extract information for each employer or school in their history section.

I am working from the following tutorial: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-easy-scraping-data-from-linkedin-profiles-david-craven/

And I am looking at this profile: https://www.linkedin.com/in/pauljgarner/?originalSubdomain=uk

Here is a partial snippet of the HTML section I am struggling with:

```
<section id="experience-section" class="pv-profile-section experience-section ember-view"><header class="pv-profile-section__card-header">
  <h2 class="pv-profile-section__card-heading">
    Experience
  </h2>

<!----></header>

  <ul class="pv-profile-section__section-info section-info pv-profile-section__section-info--has-more">
<li id="ember136" class="pv-entity__position-group-pager pv-profile-section__list-item ember-view">        <section id="1762786165" class="pv-profile-section__card-item-v2 pv-profile-section pv-position-entity ember-view">  <div class="display-flex justify-space-between full-width">
    <div class="display-flex flex-column full-width">
<a data-control-name="background_details_company" href="/company/wagestream/" id="ember138" class="full-width ember-view">          <div class="pv-entity__logo company-logo">
  <img src="https://media-exp1.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQEkzVWoORqWFQ/company-logo_100_100/0/1615996325297?e=1631145600&amp;v=beta&amp;t=SoZQKV09PqqYxYTzbjqV4XTJa7HkGUZRe4QT0jU5hmE" loading="lazy" alt="Wagestream" id="ember140" class="pv-entity__logo-img EntityPhoto-square-5 lazy-image ember-view">
</div>
<div class="pv-entity__summary-info pv-entity__summary-info--background-section ">
  <h3 class="t-16 t-black t-bold">Senior Software Engineer</h3>
  <p class="visually-hidden">Company Name</p>
  <p class="pv-entity__secondary-title t-14 t-black t-normal">
      Wagestream
        <span class="pv-entity__secondary-title separator">Full-time</span>
  </p>
    <div class="display-flex">
    <h4 class="pv-entity__date-range t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Dates Employed</span>
      <span>Apr 2021 – Present</span>
    </h4>
      <h4 class="t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Employment Duration</span>
        <span class="pv-entity__bullet-item-v2">3 mos</span>
      </h4>
  </div>

  <h4 class="pv-entity__location t-14 t-black--light t-normal block">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Location</span>
    <span>London, England, United Kingdom</span>
  </h4>
<!---->
</div>

</a>
<!---->    </div>

<!---->  </div>
</section>
```

And this is followed by more "li" sections. So the overall history section can be identified with id="experience-section", work (as opposed to education) history can be identified in the "ul" section class="pv-profile-section__section-info section-info pv-profile-section__section-info--has-more". The information for the first job in the list can be identified with "li" section id="ember136".

I am trying to get job title, company, years in job etc. from this section but can't figure out how to do it. Here is a bit of python code to show what I have tried (skipping my log-in):

```
from parsel import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import requests

path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

# driver.get method() will navigate to a page given by the URL address
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/in/pauljgarner/?originalSubdomain=uk')

text=driver.page_source
sel = Selector(text) 

# Using the "Copy xPath" option in Inspect in Google Chrome, I can manually extract the company name
sel.xpath('//*[@id="ember187"]/div[2]/p[2]/text()').extract_first()  

# This will give me all of the text in the Work Experience section
stuff = driver.find_element_by_id("experience-section")
items = html_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("ul")
items = html_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("h3")
for item in items:
    print(type(item))
    text = item.text
    print(text)
```

But these approaches are not great for an automated and systematic extraction of info from each job across profiles. What I would like to do is something like looping across "li" sections within each "ul" section, and within the "li" part, extract only the company name with class = "pv-entity__secondary-title t-14 t-black t-normal". But find_element_by_class_name only yields NoneTypes.

I'm not sure conceptually how to generate an iterable list of "ul" and "li" with selenium, and within each iteration extract specific bits of text using class names.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I came up with. I should point out I "cross posted" in a YouTube comment for the following tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4Md-koupmE

Run the whole code but replace your email and password.

First, open the browser, sign into LinkedIn, and navigate to the relevant profile

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import requests
from time import sleep

# Path to the chromedriver.exe
path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com')

# Log into LinkedIn
username = driver.find_element_by_id('session_key')
username.send_keys('mail@mail.com')

sleep(0.5)

password = driver.find_element_by_id('session_password')
password.send_keys('password')

sleep(0.5)

log_in_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('sign-in-form__submit-button')
log_in_button.click()

sleep(3)

# The example profile I am trying to scrape
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/in/pauljgarner/?originalSubdomain=uk')
sleep(3)
```

If I just start trying to extract stuff, I will get an error. It turns out that I need to scroll down to the relevant section for it to load, otherwise no data is created:

```
# The experience section doesn't load until you scroll to it, this will scroll to the section
l= driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="oc-background-section"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", l)
```

To loop through the work experience, first I identify the "id" value for it, in this case "experience-section". Grab it with "find_element_by_id" method.

```
# Get stuff in work experience section
html_list = driver.find_element_by_id("experience-section")
```

This section contains a list of "li" elements (i.e. tag value "li"), each of which contains all the work info for each past job. Create a list of these WebElement types using "find_elements_by_tag_name".

```
# Jobs listed as li sections, create list of li 
items = html_list.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
```

Looking at the source code, I notice for instance that employer names can be identified by tag "p". This generates a list, and sometimes it contains multiple items. Make sure you select what you need:

```
x = items[0].find_elements_by_tag_name("p")
print(x[0].text)
# "Company Name"
print(x[1].text)
# "Wagestream Full-time"
```

Finally loop through the "li" sections, extracting relevant info, extract strings, and print desired info (or save as row in CSV):

```
# Loop through li list, extract each piece by tag name
for item in items:
    name_job = item.find_elements_by_tag_name("h3")
    name_emp = item.find_elements_by_tag_name("p")
    more = item.find_elements_by_tag_name("h4")
    job = name_job[0].text
    emp = name_emp[1].text
    # This just cleans up the string
    yrs = [item for item in more[0].text.split('\n')][1]
    loc = [item for item in more[2].text.split('\n')][1]
    
    print(job)
    print(emp)
    print(yrs)
    print(loc)

# terminates the application
driver.quit()
```